# Is it possible and allowed on iOS to download a resource bundle and load some strings from it?

Tags: ios, nsstring, bundle, resourcebundle

I know that Apple does not allow you to download any code from the internet in your iOS application.

My question is if you can download a resource bundle that contains some string tables and load them.

The second part of the question is if Apple allows this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can download the bundle.  But nothing in the runtime would be able to use it.  You would have to write your own methods to extract the strings you need from for it.  At that point you couldn't call it a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to download content from internet. It's easy and fast. Technically use CFNetwork API that include in iOS SDK and technically is "legal" to use in apps.

In his web there are a [zone](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Who-is-using-it) with apps are in App Store now using ASIHTTPRequest.

Personnally I use this in one app but I did not send the app to the App Store yet.